# Python Endless Looping

Tags: python, for-loop, random, while-loop, infinite-loop

I have following code below:

```
for i in range(N):

    # Dispersed Source
    theta = np.random.uniform(0, np.pi, 1)
    phi = np.random.uniform(0, 2 * np.pi, 1)
    R = np.random.uniform(0, Ro, 1)

    x = R * np.sin(theta) * np.cos(phi)
    y = R * np.sin(theta) * np.sin(phi)  # ?
    z = R * np.cos(theta)

    x_vec, y_vec, z_vec, nu = particle_func(x, y, z)

    particle_trace = go.Scatter3d(
                        x=x_vec,
                        y=y_vec,
                        z=z_vec,
                        mode='lines'
                    )

    data.append(particle_trace)

    for j in range(int(nu)):
        x = x_vec[-1]
        y = y_vec[-1]
        z = z_vec[-1]

        x_vec_1, y_vec_1, z_vec_1, nu1 = particle_func(x, y, z)

        particle_trace_fiss = go.Scatter3d(
            x=x_vec_1,
            y=y_vec_1,
            z=z_vec_1,
            mode='lines'
        )

        data.append(particle_trace_fiss)
```

The problem is that the for loop needs to keep going as such:

```
for j in range(int(nu)):
        x = x_vec[-1]
        y = y_vec[-1]
        z = z_vec[-1]

        x_vec_1, y_vec_1, z_vec_1, nu1 = particle_func(x, y, z)

        particle_trace_fiss = go.Scatter3d(
            x=x_vec_1,
            y=y_vec_1,
            z=z_vec_1,
            mode='lines'
        )

        data.append(particle_trace_fiss)

 for k in range(int(nu1)):
        x = x_vec_1[-1]
        y = y_vec_1[-1]
        z = z_vec_1[-1]

        x_vec_2, y_vec_2, z_vec_2, nu2 = particle_func(x, y, z)

        particle_trace_fiss = go.Scatter3d(
            x=x_vec_2,
            y=y_vec_2,
            z=z_vec_2,
            mode='lines'
        )

        data.append(particle_trace_fiss)

 for l in range(int(nu2)):
        x = x_vec_2[-1]
        y = y_vec_2[-1]
        z = z_vec_2[-1]

        x_vec_3, y_vec_3, z_vec_3, nu3 = particle_func(x, y, z)

        particle_trace_fiss = go.Scatter3d(
            x=x_vec_3,
            y=y_vec_3,
            z=z_vec_3,
            mode='lines'
        )

        data.append(particle_trace_fiss)
```

...

Because the value of nu is a random number or zero (given from the particle_func function), the number of loops I need could potentially go on forever. That is, I could copy/paste

```
for k in range(int(nu#)):...
     data.append(particle_trace_fiss)
```

an infinite number of times and get what I am looking for (where nu# denotes the value of nu provided by the previous loop.

Please see the algorithm below for clarification:
[image]

Apologies if I missing clarity in my question, I will be happy to respond to any comments requesting clarification. All help is appreciated in advance, thanks!!

Comment: It is not very clear to me what you mean. I'm not sure I follow: "Because the value of nu is a random number or zero meaning that the number of loops could potentially go on forever." I can't tell if you trying to achieve some specific type of behavior, or if you are encountering some endless looping behavior you are trying to prevent...

Comment: Tell me if upcoming edit helps

Comment: I am trying to achieve some specific type of behavior to answer your question tho

Comment: I am also confused. My apologies if this is oversimplified, but could this be as simple as "use a while loop instead of a for loop, because you want to end only when a specific condition is met" ? https://wiki.python.org/moin/WhileLoop  Or is it simple recursion - every time you call particle_func, you have a specific number of things to append, but each call has to be handled.

Comment: I would say the latter

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you just need to wrap your `for` in a `while` loop, maybe with an arbitrary cutoff.

This code:

```
for i in range(N):

    # Dispersed Source
    theta = np.random.uniform(0, np.pi, 1)
    phi = np.random.uniform(0, 2 * np.pi, 1)
    R = np.random.uniform(0, Ro, 1)

    x = R * np.sin(theta) * np.cos(phi)
    y = R * np.sin(theta) * np.sin(phi)  # ?
    z = R * np.cos(theta)

    x_vec, y_vec, z_vec, nu = particle_func(x, y, z)

    particle_trace = go.Scatter3d(
                        x=x_vec,
                        y=y_vec,
                        z=z_vec,
                        mode='lines'
                    )

    data.append(particle_trace)

    for j in range(int(nu)):
        x = x_vec[-1]
        y = y_vec[-1]
        z = z_vec[-1]

        x_vec_1, y_vec_1, z_vec_1, nu1 = particle_func(x, y, z)

        particle_trace_fiss = go.Scatter3d(
            x=x_vec_1,
            y=y_vec_1,
            z=z_vec_1,
            mode='lines'
        )

        data.append(particle_trace_fiss)
```

Becomes this code:

```
for i in range(N):

    # Dispersed Source
    theta = np.random.uniform(0, np.pi, 1)
    phi = np.random.uniform(0, 2 * np.pi, 1)
    R = np.random.uniform(0, Ro, 1)

    x = R * np.sin(theta) * np.cos(phi)
    y = R * np.sin(theta) * np.sin(phi)  # ?
    z = R * np.cos(theta)


    arbitrary_limit = 10

    x_vec = [x]
    y_vec = [y]
    z_vec = [z]
    nu_vec = [1]

    nu = nu_vec[-1]    # Updated - keep a list of values of nu

    while int(nu) != 0:

        for j in range(int(nu)):
            x = x_vec[-1]
            y = y_vec[-1]
            z = z_vec[-1]

            x_vec, y_vec, z_vec, nu = particle_func(x, y, z)

            nu_vec.append(nu)

            particle_trace = go.Scatter3d(
                            x=x_vec,
                            y=y_vec,
                            z=z_vec,
                            mode='lines'
                        )

            data.append(particle_trace)
```

I guess the question is, how are you going to decide when to stop? Is there anything you can do to constrain the value of `nu`?

**Update:** Based on your comment, I removed the `arbitrary_limit` code. I also added a `nu_vec` to keep track of all the values of nu, per your explanation in another attempted answer.

Comment: I don't wish to stop the loop from running at the arbitrary value, in some cases if the code never finished running then it might be correct. Please see my attempted answer below

Comment: I've amended the code to remove the limit, and to keep track of the values of nu

Comment: Please see question edit, does your snippet depict algorithm? I dont sense that it could be that easy

Answer (score 0):

I thought I got it to work with the following:

```
for i in range(N):

    # Central Point Source
    # z = 0
    # x = 0
    # y = 0

    # Dispersed Source
    theta = np.random.uniform(0, np.pi, 1)
    phi = np.random.uniform(0, 2 * np.pi, 1)
    R = np.random.uniform(0, Ro, 1)

    x = R * np.sin(theta) * np.cos(phi)
    y = R * np.sin(theta) * np.sin(phi)  # ?
    z = R * np.cos(theta)

    x_vec, y_vec, z_vec, nu = particle_func(x, y, z)

    particle_trace = go.Scatter3d(
                        x=x_vec,
                        y=y_vec,
                        z=z_vec,
                        mode='lines'
                    )

    data.append(particle_trace)

    while nu != 0:

        x = x_vec[-1]
        y = y_vec[-1]
        z = z_vec[-1]

        for j in range(int(nu)):

            x_vec, y_vec, z_vec, nu = particle_func(x, y, z)

            particle_trace_fiss = go.Scatter3d(
                x=x_vec,
                y=y_vec,
                z=z_vec,
                mode='lines'
            )

            data.append(particle_trace_fiss)
```

as it does behave like I would like. However, I am confused at the point of:

```
for j in range(int(nu)):

            x_vec, y_vec, z_vec, nu = particle_func(x, y, z)
```

because there will be as many new values of nu as the value of nu in range of the for-loop. Each nu value is important. That is, I intend to generate a certain number of nu values. The problem with the above is that each nu value is overwritten by the next nu value in the for-loop. If 5 nu values are generated, I would technically need to run another for-loop on each nu value independently and the cycle continues. I hope that makes sense, any thoughts? I am thinking may i can append all the nu values in a vector and get them like that?